# Fill Gaps between Meshes with smooth surface

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing, osx

I've been trying to attempt modeling on my own for my 3D Designs after going through tutorials, but I am having an issue smoothing the gaps between meshes. In the image below I have added to UV Spheres and molded them as I would like, but I am having issues smoothing the gaps between the two to appear to have one smooth mesh:[image]

I have been adding vertices and faces manually, but the effect comes out very patchy. Is there a tool to help smooth this?

NOTE: For those not familiar with the character in the background, I will include it below for reference:
[image]

Comment: could you upload the file at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste a link here so that I can have a closer look?

Comment: @Grimlock I'll try it out

Comment: @Grimlock, having issues with upload.

Comment: in that case, could put up a perspective image of the patch from the back. I could get a few things from that. And make sure you have it on flat mode with a matcap  (press N > go to Shading on the write side toolbar > Matcap)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, there are vertices connected with edges and a face on the inside of your model.

This could have happend, when you extruded a face and then cancelled the action. Canceling the action only reverse the move position, but would have given you an extruded face at the exact same position.

You have to remove any unwanted faces/edges and possibly reconnect your vertices in that area. To do that, in *Edit Mode*, switch to [*Face Selection Mode*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/edges_faces.html#faces) (in the menu bar of the 3D View). Then select one face after the other in that area and move them around (<kbd>G</kbd>). This way you could easily identify misplaced faces. Remove a face by <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> selecting it and pressing <kbd>X</kbd> > *Faces*.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE, Alexander. I improved this answer by adding a ton of details and explanation on how to **fix** this problem. Don't forget to include a solution in future answer.